# Loop through DOM of HTML with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to loop through all the elements in the DOM structure of a html page with jQuery.
Basically only the elements within the body tags are needed.

The reason I want to do this is because I want to fetch the positions of every element
in the body structure.

I googled around and I found no answer to my question.

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$('body *').each(function() {
    // do stuff
});
```

If you have inline `<script>` tags and the like, you can add a `:not` selector to exclude those:

```
$('body *:not(script, style, noscript)').each(function() {
    // do stuff
});
```

As pointed out in the comments and the jQuery [all selector](http://api.jquery.com/all-selector/) docs, this probably won't perform very well. I haven't done any empirical testing, but this might perform better:

```
$('body').find('*').not('script, style, noscript').each(...);
```

Comment: Both selectors would perform poorly in older browsers (like IE7 and lower).  For the latter selector, you'd be better off performing a check inside your `each` callback function.

Comment: If i do this and in the // do stuff section i put alert($(this).name) I get undefined as answer. It does seem to loop over all the elements in my body. I just need to figure out how  to access them correctly

Comment: @Punxdelirium inside the function `this` points to the DOM element, so you could do `this.name`. Wrapping it with `$(this)` will turn it into a jQuery object which has no `name` property.

Comment: @Punxdelirium: you should use `this.tagName` to get the tag name.  `this.name` would point to the `name` attribute that exists on certain elements like `<a>` and `<input>`, but it doesn't apply to all elements.

Answer (score 5):

Probably the best performing solution would be to use `getElementsByTagName` instead of a jQuery selector:

```
$(document.body.getElementsByTagName("*")).each(function () {
     // Do something here
});
```

Combining `*` in a selector with anything is generally not a good idea, as pointed out in the jQuery docs themselves:

> Caution: The all, or universal, selector is extremely slow, except when used by itself.

http://api.jquery.com/all-selector/

If you really wanted to, you could use any of these variations, though none of them will give you as good performance as `getElementsByTagName`:

```
$(document.body).find("*");
$("body").find("*");
$("*", document.body);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [all selector](http://api.jquery.com/all-selector/) :

```
$("body *").each(...)
```